# Is there a way to get AdMob or AdinCube rewarded video thumbnail?

Tags: android, admob

I want to have a thumbnail in my app to show what ad the user is about to watch before they tap on it. Is there any way I can retrieve an AdMob or AdinCube thumbnail?

Comment: Hey you got any solution ?

Comment: @karanatwal.github.io I did. Just added it to this thread below. Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I got it working for `RewardedVideoAd`. Make sure that you check for null on every step since the thumbnail is not always guaranteed.

```
if (rewardedVideoAd == null) {
    return;
}

if (rewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
    Bundle adBundle = rewardedVideoAd.getAdMetadata();

    if (adBundle == null) {
        return;
    }

    Object thumbnailUrl = adBundle.get(MEDIA_URL);
    if (thumbnailUrl != null) {
        Bitmap bitmap = extractImage(thumbnailUrl.toString());
        if (bitmap != null) {
            // Set the bitmap to your view.
        }
    }
}
```